# Javascript setInterval() - Why does my "input" parameter changes to undefined?

Tags: javascript, setinterval

I've been working on the below code but couldn't figure out that why does my function parameter "input" changes to undefined after 1 second?

Here is the code:

```
<div id="new_time"></div>
         <div id='input'></div>
         <script>
             var mins = 0;
             var hrs = 0;
             var secs = 0;
             var test = 0;

             function time_calc(input)
             {
                document.getElementById('new_time').innerHTML = secs++;
                document.getElementById('input').innerHTML = input;

                if (secs>59)
                {
                    mins += 1;
                    secs = 0;
                    if (mins>59)
                    {
                        hrs += 1;
                        mins = 0;
                    }
                }
                while (secs == input) 
                {
                    clearInterval(secs_inc);
                }
                document.getElementById('new_time').innerHTML = hrs + ":" + mins + ":" + secs;
             }

             time_calc(20);
             var secs_inc = setInterval(time_calc, 1000);


         </script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What do you expect it to be? You call the function `time_calc` after one second using `setInterval`. But it is called just like that, without arguments. So the argument `input` doesn't get a value, making it undefined.

When you try to assign it to the element, it is translated to the text `undefined`.

One way to solve this, is wrapping it in a function. This can be an anonymous function:

```
var secs_inc = setInterval(function(){timecalc(20)}, 1000);
```

Dressed down example:

```js
function time_calc(input) {
  document.getElementById('input').innerText = input;
}

setInterval(function(){time_calc(20)}, 3000);
```

```html
<span id="input">Wait for it....</span>
```

If you call `setInterval(time_calc(20), 1000)`, you actually call the function `time_calc()`, and pass the *result* to setInterval.

But you must not call it. You need to pass the function itself to setInterval, so setInterval can call it later. That's why in your original snippet you passed `time_calc` without parentheses. It's just the function without the call.

What I did, is wrap the call to `time_calc(20)` in another (anonymous) function that also doesn't have arguments. And now it's the anonymous wrapper function that is called by `setInterval`, which in turn calls `time_calc` *with* an argument.

It doesn't have to be an anonymous function by the way. I think for this case it's the easiest solution, but declaring an actual named function as @sudhAnsu63 demonstrated in his answer should work too.

Comment: That worked but again I have another small question:
Why does it give the right output when using anonymous function and does not work as intended when using this:

setInterval(time_calc(20), 1000);

Don't both mean the same?

Comment: No. that's different. I added an explanation for that at the bottom of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try calling your function like this.

```
 var secs_inc = setInterval(new function(){
                               time_calc(20);}, 1000);

Or

function Calltime()
{
 time_calc(20);
}

 var secs_inc = setInterval(Calltime, 1000);
```